# Самоуничтожение объектов

Tags: python, ооп

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
```

Надо сделать так, что-бы при a <= 0 объект самоуничтожался.

Comment: оно ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865115/how-do-i-correctly-clean-up-a-python-object

Comment: объект самоуничтожается когда количество ссылок на него <= 0. этот механизм уже есть, не думаю что нужно его переизобретать

Comment: del self не работает

Comment: а какой use-case? можеть быть обычным `with` можно обойтись?

Comment: В питоне (как и во многих других языках, кроме совсем низкоуровневых) самоуничтожение объектов отсутствует

Comment: В чём именно вопрос? Вы хотите знать, как уничтожать объекты, или как отловить момент, когда атрибут объекта примет определённое значение?

Answer (score 1):

Объект не удаляется из пространства имен но любые операции с ним становяться невозможними:

```
import weakref


class MyGc(type):
    __scope = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = type.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        id_obj = id(obj)
        self.__scope[id_obj] = obj
        proxy_obj = weakref.proxy(obj, lambda: self.delete(id_obj))
        return proxy_obj

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, id_obj):
        del cls.__scope[id_obj]


class TestC(metaclass=MyGc):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def call(self):
        print('call')

    def test(self):
        print('1')

    def get_a(self):
        return self.__a

    def set_a(self, a):
        self.__a = a
        if self.__a <= 0:
            MyGc.delete(id(self))

    a = property(get_a, set_a)

    def __del__(self):
        print('__del__')


#using
c = TestC(1)
c.call()
c.a = -1
c.test()
```